# Nomenclatura javaEE

Tags: java-ee

Buenos días por la mañana,

Mi pregunta es:
¿Existe una nomenclatura estandar para nombrar las aplicaciones de javaEE?
He visto que por ejemplo unos llaman al paquete donde se albergan los pojos, bean, otros model.

Estaria bien si existiera una convencion a seguir.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto.
Un saludo.

Comment: perdon, no me refiero al nombre de las aplicaciones, si no al nombre de la estructura de paquetes

Comment: Paquete es la traducción literal de `package`, que en Java sirve para definir conjuntos de clases que tienen una relación entre sí más allá de una posible dependencia

Comment: gracias por el comentario, pero creo que no me explicado bien, me refiero a la nomenclatura que se utiliza para almacenar el codigo.

Comment: Ejemplo: pquete1 bussines, paquete2: persistence, etc. He estado buscando alguna nomenclatura internacional pero no he visto nada, no se si existira algun ISO o algún estandar para que todo nombremos igual todos los paquetes

Comment: No hay un estándar, hay convenciones y hay varias: para los bean de persistencia: modelo o dominio y dao o repositorio, para negocio: servicio, facade... En general la anotación de Spring suele marcar la *moda* en Java

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es la anotacion que sigo actualmente. Un saludo